# In this world of pseudo forces what is real?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I was learning concept of pseudo force and encountered a problem which I found pretty interesting,

[image]

I am told that the surface in contact of wedge and box having mass $m$ is frictionless and I am being asked of the minimum force such that box of mass small $m$ will not slide.

By using concept of pseudo force I arrived at result $$F=(m+M)g\tan(\theta)$$ which is correct but I ask being an observer on ground what force is restricting the motion of the box? If it is Force $F$ which is applied than please explain how, because as per me it seems force $F$ will only accelerate box on the wedge downwards.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! I would suggest that you [edit] your question to choose a more descriptive title and elaborate on why you think that $F$ will accelerate the box downwards. Thanks!

Comment: Reminder to those who are voting to close: conceptual questions in the context of homework problems are on-topic

Answer (score 1):

There are only two forces acting on the box - it’s weight $mg$ and the normal force $N$ exerted by the wedge on the box. Since the box does not move vertically we know that the vertical component of $N$ must be equal and opposite to $mg$, so $N \cos \theta =mg$. The horizontal component of $N$ accelerates the box to the right with acceleration

$$a = \frac {N \sin \theta} m = N g \tan \theta$$

Since the box does not slide down the wedge, the force $F$ must be sufficient to accelerate both the wedge and the box together to the right with acceleration $a$.

Alternatively, you can consider the horizontal forces on the wedge alone to get

$$F - N\sin \theta = Ma$$

So it is the normal force exerted by the wedge on the box that restricts the vertical motion of the box. The horizontal motion of the box is unrestricted - it is simply that the wedge is accelerating to the right at the same rate as the box.